# browsersync - how to deal with sites which switch between http and https?

Tags: https, proxy, browser-sync

I work on a site which switches to https when the user inputs personal details.  When it does this, the browser displays:

This site can’t be reached

localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.

Obviously, the details are becoming encrypted and can't be displayed.
In the docs they suggested using the https address as a parameter to start the browsersync proxy server.  However, this did not make any difference.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not secure to only use https on some pages : it's vulnerable to Man In the Middle (MiTM) attacks, it doesn't allow you to use HSTS (the only secure way to prevent MITM), and it makes the configuration harder. And, if you use http2, https can be faster than http.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I gave up with it for the time being as I had other priorities.  The https pages have inputs, but the http pages do not, so I don't think it will apply.

Comment: Your solution only prevent *passive* attacks. Active attacks can do much more: in your http page it can replace secure https link to your secure page by insecure http links and do a man in the middle to intercept any content of your supposed secure page. It's how sslstrip works. To only way to prenvent it is HSTS, and it require https on all the webpage.ssltrip is an easy tool that anybody can use, it's not a complex attack.